# Android cursor query

Tags: android

Hii ı  make a dropdown  navigation which  has  some priority and  when  ı click  one  of them 
ı want to pull  some  information  from databse  but  ı can't get the  result from database.
 in my  project  ı  have  a  main activiy  and simplecursoradapter .In main activity ı have  some priority level  in a dropdown in actionbar.  when  ı select  one of them , ı  filter database   according  to their  priority via  cursor  and send  the  result  cursor  to  simplecursoradapter    this is my navigation code  in the mainActivity

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, actions);
       getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

     OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {

         filterPriorityItems(itemPosition);
           todoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
      }


  };

getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);
```

I send the itemposition to  a  filterFunction  which  is  in  main  activiy  also

```
    private void filterPriorityItems(int itemPosition) {
    String where=null;
    ContentResolver resolver =getContentResolver();
    switch(itemPosition){
    case 0:
        where = MyOpenHelper.PRIORITY + ">" + 5;
    cursor = resolver.query(ContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, FROM, where,
            null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
        break;
    case 1:
        where = MyOpenHelper.PRIORITY + "<" + 7 + "and " + ">" + 5;
        cursor = resolver.query(ContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, FROM, null,
                null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        break;
    case 2:
        where = MyOpenHelper.PRIORITY + "<" + 7 + "and " + ">" + 5;
        cursor = resolver.query(ContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, FROM, null,
                null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        break;
    case 3:
        where = MyOpenHelper.PRIORITY + "<" + 7 + "and " + ">" + 5;
        cursor = resolver.query(ContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, FROM, null,
                null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        break;
        default:

    }


        }
}
```

According  to this  filterfunction  ı want  to return  a  cursor  for  sending   the  cursor  in the my simplecursoradapter 
  which  is

```
todoAdapter = new SimpleCursorToDoAdapter(this, R.layout.todo_list_item , cursor, FROM, TO);
```

but  when  i send to cursor  to  my adapter,  it don't  change the  cursor that  I want  to  filter my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved  my  problem  and I want  to explain  this.
The  solution of  this  problem  is  fragmentation.  I create  a new fragment in the my main activity  and   I wrote  this  code

```
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {

                fragment = new MyTodoListFragment();
                FragmentTransaction ft =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.my_new,fragment,actionlist[itemPosition]);
                ft.commit();

                return true;



            }
```

I send  the  item position in the my  fragment. I get  this  item  via getTag in the OnAttach()  function after  that  I move  the  code  in my activity  to  fragment
and the  problem is solved